How can I navigate back through nested array of Records
I am building a database of arrays of TFileTree records, where each record can hold an array of TFileTrees.
type
  pFileTree = ^TFileTree;
  tFileTree = record
    Parent: pFileTree;
    FileName: String;
    L0CodeData: Array of TItemRecord;
    L1CodeData: Array of TItemRecord;
    Includes: Array of tFileTree;
  end;


This structure allows me to build up a hierarchical database of TreeFile records; e.g:
MainTreeFile
            | ChildTreeFile0
            | ChildTreeFile1
                            | ChildTreeFile0
etc...

In order to navigate back from a child to the parent, I have added a Parent item to the record.
The problem I am having is how to add in the parent.
In the example below, where TreeItem is a tFileTree record, I get a compiler error:

incompatible types pFileTree and Char

TreeItem.Includes[high(TreeItem.Includes)].Parent := ^TreeItem;

Declaring Parent as a TFileTree gives me a different compiler error:

fFileTree is not yet completely defined

How can I get this link back to the parent record?

Referencing a variable by pointer happens via @, dereferencing a pointer to a type via ^: @TreeItem is of type PFileTree, and TreeItem.Parent^ is of type TFileTree. If that's too complicated for you consider using objects.
